# Alarm clock using Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, alarm

Here I have a code of an alarm clock:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Seconds: ");
        int seconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000);

        Timer timer = new Timer(100);

        timer.Elapsed += MakeSound;

        timer.Enabled = true;

        GC.KeepAlive(timer);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MakeSound(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
```

As you can see, it doesn't look so promising because I am using Thread.Sleep.

It still works if I use

`Timer timer = new Timer(seconds * 1000);` instead of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000);`

But it doesn't beep constantly, just between interval of `seconds * 1000` seconds until user presses Enter. Can I make it any better?

Comment: No it beeps every 100 ms (0.1s) after the seconds occurred because thats exactly what you asked to it do

Comment: For "human" timespans it's usually better to either a) use windows task scheduler rather than a dedicated program or b) use shorter sleeps and check whether the "expected" wall-clock time has arrived (or is now in the past), rather than trying to create a timer/sleep that lasts for exactly the right amount of time. That being said, not at all clear *what you're trying to achieve*.

Comment: tell us what you want it to do - it't not clear from this. Also, this is good for a toy program, but you need to think of something else for a more accurate clock. Sleeping for 1s sleeps for _at least_ 1s, as in, more than 1s, and how much more is not defined.

Comment: @mikelegg I'm trying make an alarm clock. When a user enters an integer value (for seconds), it waits until those seconds has elapsed and beeps every 0.1s until user presses Enter.

Comment: I ran this. I entered 3. It waited about 3s. Then it beeped alot. What is the problem? is it that the time between beeps at the end is irregular?

Comment: You could get rid of the `Sleep` call and use your alternate approach of `new Timer(seconds * 1000)`.  Now simply change the [Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Timer to 100 in your `MakeSound()` method.  Move the declaration of your Timer out to class level and make it static.  You also won't need `GC.KeepAlive` anymore.

Comment: @Idle_Mind cheers! this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the constructor overloads for `System.Threading.Timer`, you'll see that you can specify the `dueTime`, as well as the `period`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7(v=vs.110).aspx

So, instead of using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * seconds)`, use

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(MakeSound), null, 1000 * seconds, 100);
```